# Can you limit the number of options that get listed in the react-select dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I would like to show only 30 options in the dropdown using the react-select dropdown. Is this possible ? I would like to display everything else based on the autocomplete feature of the library. Is there a configuration that i can set ?

Comment: Render just 30 options then

Comment: What do you mean by "display everything else based on the autocomplete feature of the library?" Can you not just pass it the first 30 options of your array?

Comment: If i render just the 30 options, how will i be able to see the rest of the options. Take for example, I have 100 options.. and I don't want to display all 100 due to performance issues and better user experience. I would like to display just 30 and then user can see the others by typing in part of the value based on which it will display by filtering

Comment: I think in that case you are going to want to create your own [menu component](https://react-select.com/components#defining-components) and pass it into the `components` prop

Comment: I was thinking, can you pick the 30 elements after search/fetch when giving to the dropdown or when mapping